# FFmpeg export codec not supported by Samsung

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to render videos (concatenating image files with audio and then applying speed and volume filters) to export videos to upload to TikTok. As a result, I must first move the videos to my phone.

I do not understand why my phone (S20) will happily play one of the videos (codec information pictured first), but presents an error "Codec not supported" when playing the other (information second).

[image: The Supported File]

[image: The unsupported file]

The codec information is from VLC, and as you can see, both videos have identical Codecs (H264-MPEG4).

From analysing the information, the only conclusion I come to is that it has something to do with the fact that the "Decoded Format" differs across the videos. How can I change my export command on the latter so my phone supports the codec?

**CONCATENATION CODE**
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i {path_temp}\\clips.txt -c copy -y "{path_temp}\\{title}_a.mp4`

**FILTER CODE**
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:a "volume={volume}" -y temp.mp4"`

**SECOND FILTER**
`ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts={1/speed}*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo={speed}[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -y output.mp4`

Comment: Your question does not seem to be related to software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're re-encoding, do it in one step.

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i {path_temp}\\clips.txt -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts={1/speed}*PTS,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a]volume={volume},atempo={speed}[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -y output.mp4`

`format=yuv420p` generates to a widely compatible pixel format.

Comment: You sir are a legend @Gyan! You decreased my processing time by 40s too! Thank you very much for the suggestion!